# How do I download a file from a private repo on GitHub which I don't own (in Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, github, download

I'm trying to make a simple JAVA program for gameservers which helps users work together on a project without having to be able to access the files of the server directly. Say 2 users are writing scripts. They upload it to the repo in the folder "/scripts". Now they log in onto a game server (specificly Minecraft), type a command in chat and the program will then connect to the repo and download the whole folder.

What I have for now:
I tried the GitHub API made by kohsuke AND the one made/distributed by Eclipse. In both of them I managed to connect to the service/GitHub API with my username and a private token. But then I have no idea how to get the file. 
Kohsuke throws an IOException when I try to do this:

```
GitHub github = something with connectWithCredentials(Config.USERNAME,Config.TOKEN);
GHRepository repo = github.getRepository(Config.URL);
String downloadURL = repo.getFileContent(Config.FOLDER_NAME).getDownloadUrl();
```

Btw the message I get from exception.getMessage is something like "Server returned response 200: OK" which is something I would NOT expect coming with a Java exception.
With the Eclipse API I didn't even manage to find a way to get something like a download URL at all.

Comment: The end user would go through an Oauth web flow to provide a token to access their repository.

Comment: Sadly I didn't understand what Oauth actually is/does or how to use it in my Java code. I was told all I need is to connect to github via username and private token. :/
Also that doesn't help me with my problem of not knowing how to download files with the Eclipse API. @osowskit